# search in limited number of record MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, find, limit, record

I want to search in the first 1000 records of my document whose name is CityDB. I used the following code:

```
db.CityDB.find({'index.2':"London"}).limit(1000)
```

but it does not work, it return the first 1000 of finding, but I want to search just in the first 1000 records not all records. Could you please help me.

Thanks,
Amir

Comment: Can you limit and then find?

Comment: I did try it but it does not work

Answer (score 4):

Note that there is no guarantee that your documents are returned in any particular order by a query as long as you don't sort explicitely. Documents in a new collection are usually returned in insertion order, but various things can cause that order to change unexpectedly, so don't rely on it. By the way: Auto-generated _id's start with a timestamp, so when you sort by _id, the objects are returned by creation-date.

Now about your actual question. When you first want to limit the documents and then perform a filter-operation on this limited set, you can use the aggregation pipeline. It allows you to use [$limit-operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit) first and then use the [$match-operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) on the remaining documents.

```
db.CityDB.aggregate( 
 // { $sort: { _id: 1 } }, // <- uncomment when you want the first 1000 by creation-time
    { $limit: 1000 },
    { $match: { 'index.2':"London" } }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to achieve this:

**1)** You have a [global counter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) and every time you input data into your collection you add a field `count = currentCounter` and increase `currentCounter` by 1. When you need to select your first k elements, you find it this way

```
db.CityDB.find({
  'index.2':"London",
  count : {
    '$gte' : currentCounter - k
  }
})
```

This is not atomic and might give you sometimes more then k elements on a heavy loaded system (but it can support indexes).

Here is another approach which works nice in the shell:

**2)**  Create your dummy data:

```
var k = 100;
for(var i = 1; i<k; i++){
  db.a.insert({
     _id : i,
     z: Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 10)
  })
}

output = [];
```

And now find in the first `k` records where `z == 3`

```
k = 10;
db.a.find().sort({$natural : -1}).limit(k).forEach(function(el){
  if (el.z == 3){
     output.push(el)
  }
})
```

as you see your output has correct elements:

```
output
```

I think it is pretty straight forward to modify my example for your needs.

**P.S.** also take a look in aggregation framework, there might be a way to achieve what you need with it.